# What's the maximum tag count supported in the notes app?

Tags: ios, notes.app

Now that iOS supports tags natively in the Notes app what's the limit on the number of tags one can create?

I don't see anything mentioned in the corresponding support page

> Use Tags and Smart Folders in Notes on your iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch
>
> https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212507

and nothing is mentioned in the help page from the notes app itself
[image: Notes app tags description page]

(by way of comparison Google keep has a maximum label count of [50](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/8642562/google-keep-has-told-me-the-label-limit-has-been-reached-surely-there-can-t-be-a-limit-on-them?hl=en))